# Pass XML tag value to be used as search pattern

Tags: c#

below is my code which is suppose to do the following:

1. extract the XML tag value
2. pass it as search pater
3. find matching pattern (based on the Tag Value in this file name)
4. copy it to C:\MR

Code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
    xml.Load(@"C:\Temp\XML\BBG_20001.xml");

    XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/FileDump/Message/Attachment");
    foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
    {
        string FileName = xn["FileName"].InnerText;
        string FileID = xn["FileID"].InnerText;
    }
}

public void FileCopy(string[] args)
{
    string fileName = "";

    string sourcePath = @"C:\temp\MR\";
    string targetPath = @"C:\MR";


    string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName);
    string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);

    string pattern = @"FileName";
    var matches = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\temp\MR\")
        .Where(path => Regex.Match(path, pattern).Success);

    foreach (string file in matches)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(file);
        fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file);
        Console.WriteLine(fileName);
        destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);
        System.IO.File.Copy(file, destFile, true);

    }
}
```

when I compile the code it gives me no error but I'm struggling to see why it is not producing the results expected.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: I can't see why you expect this to do anything. Have you tried debugging? Single-stepping will give you a Big Clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things look a bit strange:

1. You declare two string variables inside your foreach loop (in main) that are not referenced elsewhere.
2. You never invoke FileCopy.

Comment: I solved my issue if anyone is interested I can post the code